# Use Django-Storages with IAM Instance Profiles

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

Django-Storages provides an S3 file storage backend for Django.  It lists
`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as required settings.  If I am using an AWS Instance Profile to provide S3 access instead of a key pair, how do I configure Django-Storages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply omit these parameters from your settings.

The [Django-Storages documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) now explains this:

> If `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are not set, boto3 internally looks up IAM credentials.

The way this works under the hood is that if you do not provide them, Django-Storages passes `None` to boto3, which uses the machine's privileges instead of a key pair.  If the machine has an associated Instance Profile, this is what gets used.  (See the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) for more on boto3's credential hierarchy)

---

Thanks to [@ChrisShenton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61942402/2800876) for pointing out that the Django-Storages docs had been updated.  The Django-Storages docs previously listed these configuration parameters as required, which was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The docs now explain this:

> If `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are not set, boto3 internally looks up IAM credentials.